# Overlapping content with transparent WebView background

Tags: android, webview

I'm using a `WebView` to display HTML content, including a JavaScript function to show or hide sections of the page when links are pressed. By default, all sections are hidden. Everything works fine until I set the background of the WebView to be transparent, so that a static image is displayed behind it.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

HTML section:

```
<a class="togglelink-show" onclick="toggle('zone1');">Test</a>
<div id="zone1" style="display:none">
    <p>Some random text that's normally hidden</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle(id) {
    ele = document.getElementById(id);

    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

As I wrote, those two work fine, until I set the WebView to have a transparent background using `webView.setBackgroundColor(0);` After that, when trying to open a section, sometimes the WebView does not re-layout properly, and content overlaps with the sections below.

Refreshing the page, or using `webView.clearView()` don't work because then the page is refreshed with the section closed. Any suggestions?

If there's another way to display a static image behind the webview, that's resized to fit the screen exactly, that could work too. (I'm a bit rusty with HTML, and could only remember how to tile a background image, which certainly isn't what I want.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this, but in a very random manner. I don't know which elements were the magic trick, but what I've ended up with is something like this:

Added an empty div above the main content window, and edited the styles:

```
<div id="fixedBackground"><img src="" width="0%" height="0%"/></div>
//From the stylesheet:
#fixedBackground    { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
.content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
```

This makes the background to the WebView show through, and has everything reposition itself properly after opening or closing sections.

Answer (score 3):

i met this too.
and my solution is call "webView.setBackgroundColor(0x01010101);" 
i think it's more or less than transparent.

Comment: Thanks for this - I am using "setBackgroundColor(0x01000000);"